# Using Bash variable for string literal to pass to a Regex expression through Perl line

Tags: regex, bash, perl

Using Bash variable for string literal to pass to a Regex expression through Perl line:

I have a Bash script to make some edits to an XML file through RegEx statement. The statement works good in Perl but not in Bash but the issue is passing a variable into the substitution part of the Regex statement. Using string literals all is good, but not practical since needed to be programmatic. Below is an small snippet.

Example XML Test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <NodeA>12345678</NodeA>
    <NodeB>5551212</NodeB>
    <NodeC>a1fea1f8</NodeC>
</Root>
```

Example works with literal string:

```
xml=`cat Test.xml`
value="TESTttt"
# Perl flavor 
new_xml=`echo ${xml} | perl -ne 's/(\<NodeB\>).*?(\<\/NodeB\>)/\1New_String\2/m;print $_'`
```

How does one pass the variable `value` into the substitution string of the Regex statement, replacing 'New_String' to be logical?

Comment: There is probably an `argv` construct Perl uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that. String interpolation and feeding shell into perl is a dirty thing to do. Especially for XML, which is a data format with a very strict specification. 
Perl has some good XML parsing options though.

Try something like this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new();
{
    local $/;
    $twig->parse(<DATA>);
}

my $NodeB = $twig->root->first_child('NodeB');

my $old_text = $NodeB->text();
print $old_text, "\n";

$NodeB->set_content('Some New Text');

$twig->set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig->print;

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <NodeA>12345678</NodeA>
  <NodeB>5551212</NodeB>
  <NodeC>a1fea1f8</NodeC>
</Root>
```

(You can use `parsefile` instead to read `text.xml`, I've just inlined it as `DATA` for the sake of an example).

Comment: Sobrique, This appears to be a good solution and simplifies the process. The solution works well but will expand the usage over the weekend.

Comment: There's sometimes edge cases where you trade off capability of one approach against familiarity and experience of another. But as you stretch what you're trying to do - the advantages of pure perl over shell scripts start to show.